# Populating a GridView with ImageViews dynamically/programmatically using a ImageAdapter

Tags: android, gridview, dynamic, adapter, flickr

I try to develop an Android App which allows the user to fetch data from flickr and show it in a `GridView` (with some nice 3D-Animation). After some adventures i got it almost running, but now I'm stuck.

---

Here's the problem:

I got a UI Thread "LoadPhotosTask" which gets the pictures from flickr, just like the open source application [photostream](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/#trunk/Photostream). In the method `onProgressUpdate(LoadedPhoto... value)` of that subclass I call `addPhoto()`. Until now everythings fine - I got some nice Bitmap and Flickr.photo data with all the information I need.

```
        @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(LoadedPhoto... value) {

        addPhoto(value);
    }
```

On the other hand I have got a `GridView`. Now I want to fill it with the Photos. It has got an adapter called `ImageAdapter` (which extends `BaseAdapter`, see this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)). If I use an array inside the `ImageAdapter` class I can populate the `GridView` with some sample images. But if I want to populate it at runtime, I don't know what to do.

How do I have to set up the getView method in the `ImageAdapter`? I was trying to fill the array inside the `ImageAdapter` class with my values in `addPhoto`, but it doesn't display anything.

So first of all I was setting up the array with the amount of Photos i wanted to display in the grid like that (code is inside the `ImageAdapter` class):

```
// class variable
private ImageView[] mThumbIds;

    [...] 

    public void setupArray(int count) {
            this.mThumbIds = new ImageView[count];
        }
```

Then I call this method with the lenght of my photolist:

```
    final Flickr.PhotoList list = params[0];
        final int count = list.getCount();
        int helper = 0;
    imagead.setupArray(count);
```

Afterwards I call the getView method manually inside the addPhoto method:

```
private void addPhoto(LoadedPhoto... value) {

    ImageView image = (ImageView) mInflater.inflate(
    R.layout.grid_item_photo, null);
    image.setImageBitmap(value[0].mBitmap);
    image.setTag(value[0].mPhoto);

    imagead.setmThumbIds(image, value[0].mPosition);
    imagead.getView(value[0].mPosition, null, mpicturesGrid);

}
```

That is the getView method inside ImageAdapter:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
        // attributes

        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(EDGE_LENGTH,
        EDGE_LENGTH));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {

        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageDrawable(mThumbIds[position].getDrawable());
    imageView.setTag(mThumbIds[position].getTag());

    return imageView;

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing a key part.

When you use an `Adapter` you have a method called [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()).
The logic you are missing there is the following:

When creating the `Adapter` for the `GridView` stay with a reference for the list that the adapter will use. Something like:

```
private ArrayList<Photo> mPhotos;
private BaseAdapter mAdapter;
private GridView mGridView;

onCreate:

/* other things here */

mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mPhotos);
mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

What you addPhoto should do is the following:

```
mPhotos.add(photo);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I think that's the point.Ok lets see... If I understand correctly, MyAdapter will be my ImageAdapter, won't it? But then, mPhotos will be the context? I apologize, I read through several Adapter tuts, but I still don't get it. How do I have to set up the ImageAdapter/MyAdapter correctly?

Comment: Yes, MyAdapter == ImageAdapter. Nope, mPhotos is just a list which will hold the photos. For your case, it would be better if you extend ImageAdapter with ArrayAdapter<Photo> in the constructor you can pass it a list of items.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm doing the same thing with Gallery. I thought as much that the method would be found in the adapter since nothing is in gallery. SO never fails me. :)

Comment: I am fairly new to Android programming, can someone post the whole example - Gallery Activity and the calling Activity? It's a bit hard for me to follow. Thanks.

Comment: Macarse thanks for this answer ! I was using ArrayAdapter before, and I forgot that it's calling that method when add or addAll is called. Now I've implemented my own ImageAdapter and I forgot to add this notification. One more time - Thank you!